# Passport expiration requirement for Jordan Visa

Tags: visas, passports, jordan

After we booked our ticket for Jordan we realized that my wife's passport expires in about 6.5 months from now. It will expire in 5 month 29 days when we land in Jordan. Their visa requirement says that the passport should be valid for at least 6 months.

We were planning to apply for the visa on arrival but now I am worried that my wife might be denied for the visa. **Q:** Has anyone have experience with this?

We already sent an email to the Jordanian Consulate and awaiting their response but any insight here will be helpful.

Also will this have any impact on our return flight to the USA? We have an Indian passport and US green card.

**Update** - Thanks for the answers everyone! We got similar response from Jordan consulate to what people have already mentioned here. We don't have enough time to renew the passport before the trip. So, We are changing our plans and will instead fly to Italy where they only require the passport to be valid for 90 days from the date of the departure and we already have valid Schengen Visa.

Comment: Don't wait for answers. Get a new passport. NOW.

Comment: Unfortunately we realized this very late and not enough time to renew the passport. So, we are changing the plan and will rather fly to Italy instead of Jordan.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The requirement for Jordan is that your passport must be valid for 6 months after your planned *departure* from Jordan, not arrival.  Thus you will be even further outside the requirement than you've implied.

Whether or not she will be given a visa-on-arrival is largely a moot point - she will almost certainly not be allowed board the flight to get Jordan as she doesn't meet the requirements for travel, and thus the airline will almost certainly not let her board the flight.

Your only safe option is to renew the passport before departure. If you can't do that before your currently planned departure you will need to delay the trip.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if her application for a Jordanian visa will be denied, but even if she is issued a visa she won't be able to fly.

Because they must return passengers to the passenger's departure point at the airline's expense if the passenger is not admitted at their destination, airlines check carefully to see that passengers have the correct paperwork.

Upon checking (airlines use the [Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) database), the airline will see that Jordan requires visitors to have six months' remaining passport validity upon departure. Because her current passport will have expired less than six months before she plans to depart Jordan, she doesn't qualify for entry and the airline will not permit her to board the flight.

Thus, she should renew new passport before the trip. With a valid green card, she won't have difficulty returning to the USA.